# Open AFS problem

Tags: 14.04, apt, software-installation

In Ubuntu 14.04.4-desktop-amd64 I tried to install OpenAfs

```
sudo apt-get install openafs-client openafs-modules-dkms openafs-krb5
```

and there was a problem:

```
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.2.0-27-generic (x86_64)
```

which is due to:

```
configure: error: Couldn't guess your Linux version 2
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need a newer version of openafs.

You could check by looking at the configure script from the openafs module:

```
grep -n AFS_SYSKVERS= /usr/src/modules/openafs/configure
5920:                  2.2.*) AFS_SYSKVERS=22 ;;
5921:                  2.4.*) AFS_SYSKVERS=24 ;;
5922:                  2.6.* | 3.*) AFS_SYSKVERS=26 ;;
```

The missing 4.* in the case statement means that there is no support for 4.* kernels yet.

Answer (score 1):

You may need this even if you upgrade your kernel and afs modules are not rebuilt:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openafs/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install --reinstall openafs-client openafs-modules-dkms
```

With the dkms installed, things should become more stable with kernel upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? It works for me on Ubuntu 14.04.4

```
$ sudo apt-get purge openafs-client
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openafs/stable
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt install openafs-client
```